# Use of semicolon to separate items within a list that appears within a parenthetical element

Tags: semicolons, parentheticals

> For low-complexity ML detection, breadth-first approaches, such as ... , have been chosen as a reasonable alternative..."

There are three examples of said breadth-first approaches, which appear in the following form:

> A        (item 1)
>
> B and C  (item 2)
>
> D        (item 3)

Should I use semicolons to separate these three items? As in

> A; B and C; and D

Comment: The above is a specific case of a more general question that I meant to ask about. For example, within a parenthetical element, should the items of a series be separated by commas or semicolons, regardless of whether one of the items contains a compound term joined by the word "and"?

Comment: For example,

", such as A, B, and C, ..."

or

", such as A; B; and C, ..."?

Comment: Use a comma unless the list gets complicated. A list of single items can always (should I say, almost?) fine to separate with just a comma. In your specific example, a semicolon would be preferred because B and C are a compound unit; and that's only because it makes it easier to read/parse.

Comment: While it is true that the semicolon can be used to separate list items, it is generally only worth doing if a comma or two is required, perhaps for setting off parenthetical material, *within* one or more of the items. (This is not the case when one of the items is "B & C.") If this condition applies when the entire list is contained within some sort of parenthesis, well frankly I'd say your best bet is to re-engineer the whole structure--it is just getting too g--d--ed complicated.

Comment: Depending on the complexity, I would use bullet points. Readability dramatically influences comprehension.